# Add JLabel in JScrollable JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jscrollpane, jlabel

i am new on Java. In fact i put a J Label inside a J Panel. I have set the layout of J Panel to null , then i have set the bounds  of J Label greater than the width and height of the panel . Surely it will not be visible , but i have add a JScrollPane to the Panel , but it is still not visible . Is it possible or impossible , or is there any other method?

```
    JPanel pnel = new JPanel();
    pnel.setLayout(null);
    JScrollPane txtstmtPane = new JScrollPane(pnel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon ( "icon/filter.jpg" );
    Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("icon/filter.jpg"));
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(icon);
    label.setBounds(500, 500, 40, 30);
    pnel.add(label);
```

Comment: is it just your image that's not appearing?

Comment: Where is your `icon` directory located?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

1. Forget the `null` layout, take that out.
2. Forget the `setBounds` take that out.
3. Put your `icon` directory straight in the `src` --> `src/icon/filter.jpg`
4. Use

   ```
   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass.getResource("/icon/filter.jpg");
   JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
   pnel.add(label);
   ```

Comment: but i want to position the JLabel

Comment: Use a LayoutManager. See [Laying out Component Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for details on how to use different layout managers.